# Devise signin and redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

What's the best way to redirect to the target link upon signin with devise:

1) go to localhost
2) click link for restricted page
3) sign in (either as user or admin - two separate models)
4) logs in and redirect to restricted link in 2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `after_sign_in_path_for` method to do this

Link:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to%3A-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Its also mentioned in the README page:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 0):

Always check wiki, before asking. Here is a devise wiki page about [this.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out)

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(resource) || some_default_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the after_sign_in_path_for method in your application controller:
[Description](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Or you can change the default devise Sign_in and Sign_out routes^^:
[Description](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Comment: from what i understand, that looks like it will redirect to the current path after signin or a default path.  I'm looking for the target path if you click on a link and you are forced to sign in. Will this handle that as well?